# Like Cannot get FB Like button to work in Dreamweaver

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook-like

I have followed step 1 and step 2 in order to add the "like" button to a web site that I am developing.  I am using Dreamweaver (Cs5.5) to build the site.  This button is a "must have" for the person I am doing the site for!

I insert the code EXACTLY as the instructions state and I cannot get the button to appear...what is strange is that I am working off of a template and there is no  - there is {body...}...I have inserted the code after using the like button 'builder' at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins

I have tried numerous times to post the code - it will not "translate" thru this venue.  Also tried sending image of code - I'm a new user and I am not allowed.  So, let me know what I can get you to answer my question - very frustrating.

I insert everything - nothing.  I view in iexplorer 8 - nothing.  Please help!  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

If follow this link, it will take you to a page that will generate the code for you.  On the page's code generator form the first step to fill in is headed "Facebook Page URL (?)".  In the box below it replace the word "platform" with the name of the Facebook page to want to connect to your web site.  This really works.  I am also a newbie and it was the first time I had to do this.  I entered the code in a div I called "FaceBookFeed".

Comment: I was also using DreamWeaver and IE 8

Comment: Thanks for responding Toni - I don't know what I am doing wrong, but it still doesn't work.  I did the div and placed just under the body script - then placed where I wanted the button to go - nothing.  Can I email you my code if it is not too much trouble??